# Почему не выводится вся выборка цикла?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, циклы, woocommerce

Не выводится вся выборка цикла
Есть сайт на wordpress + woocommerce. Установил [плагина Woo Gift : Advanced Woocommerce Gift Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/woo-gift-advanced-woocommerce-gift-plugin/10685086) и столкнулся с такой проблемой. В запросе с бд товаров

```
$args_post = array('post_type' => 'product','posts_per_page'=>-1);
$loop_post = new WP_Query( $args_post );
```

директива вывода всех элементов **'posts_per_page'=>-1** зарезает последующий вывод плагина. Если вместо -1 назначить 50 или 100, например, то все выведется ок, но ограниченное количество. 
Как вывести именно все элементы выборки?
з.ы. интересно, что на зеркале на другом хостинге все ок и с -1.. 
Может быть это проблема на хостинге?

Answer (score 1):

-1 выводит все посты, сделайте 9999 вместо -1, вы все равно вряд ли столько в вукомерц зальете, к тому времени вам потребуется хороший впс)

Comment: да, это понятно. выводит не больше 400 товаров, хотя на деле нужно более 2000..

Comment: а после этого цикла стоит wp_reset_postdata? я думаю еще есть смысл лог проверить в момент открытия страницы, раз вы говорите в хостингах разница...

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь! Ошибка была в самом плагине - не в том месте закрыта скобка в цикле, но в другом файле. Видимо, разные версии php на хостингах отрабатывали этот момент по разному